# Where are the BlizzCon missions in the story?

Tags: starcraft-2

At BlizzCon 2011, fans got to play 2 of the single player missions for Heart of the Swarm. Are they even included in the campaign? If so, where are they in the story, i.e. how far into the story are they?

Comment: The game has been out less then 24 hours.  I suggest you play the game.  Of course HoTs has gone through some changes since 2012 also.

Answer (score 3):

The two missions that I remember being playable at Blizzcon were Harvest of Screams and Domination.

Harvest of Screams is the first mission on Kaldir.  Domination is the first mission on Char.  These are the first two planets you get to choose from, so either one could be the fourth map you play.